# JavaScript "<SCRIPT>" in Image src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following JavaScript function.

```
var LogoUrl = function() {
    document.write('views/img/common/site-logo.svg');
}
```

And I want to have this function used in a html img src attribute.

Here is a example though this syntax wouldn't work, it should give you an idea of what I am looking for.

```
<img class="site-logo" src="<script> LogoUrl() </script>" alt="Site Logo">
```

And hoping this would export the following in the browser

```
<img class="site-logo" src="views/img/common/site-logo.svg" alt="Site Logo">
```

What is the best approach to doing this?

Comment: Learn basic html. `src` is required to be a URI. You can't just dump **OTHER** html into any place you want and expect it to work. If you want to dynamically change the src of an image, then you'll have to run that code ELSEWHERE and find the image in the DOM, then fiddle with that DOM element's src attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following instead:

```
<script>
    document.write('<img class="site-logo" src="' + 'views/img/common/site-logo.svg' + '" alt="Site Logo">');
</script>
```

Since the script tag is indeed a tag, you can't put it inside the attributes of another tag.

---

A much better approach however would be the following:

Prepare a span element for the element to appear in, and give it a specific `id`. This would be your HTML:

```
This is my image: <span id="myImg"></span>.
```

and this will be your jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('<img>').class('site-logo')
        .attr('src', 'views/img/common/site-logo.svg')
        .attr('alt', 'Site Logo')
        .appendTo('#myImg');
});
```

Alternatively, instead of preparing a span, you could prepare the image without defining a `src` attribute, with the following HTML:

```
This is my image: <img id="myImg" class="site-logo" alt="Site Logo">.
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myImg').attr('src', 'views/img/common/site-logo.svg');
});
```

Comment: Hmm but the framework I'm developing around my application I was hoping it to be flexible where it didn't have to create the entire element with the function. I had already thought of that. You think that's the best option?

Comment: I think either of my placeholder solutions is the best solution. The `document.write` solution is generally not as good as simply modifying the DOM. I personally always avoid `document.write`, because it can sometimes have unwanted effects (running `document.write` after the DOM tree has loaded will cause the whole page to be blanked).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `$(document).ready()` to set the image src.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $('img.site-logo').attr('src', 'views/img/common/site-logo.svg');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this - but this makes it obstructive.

```
<script>document.write("<img class=\"site-logo\" src=\"views/img/common/site-logo.svg\" alt=\"Site Logo\">")</script>
```

It is also not very organised because it ties everything so much with the markup that you might as well just have it as markup.

You're better off doing it properly by changing the src property

```
var logo = document.getElementsByClassName('site-logo')[0];
logo.src = 'http://www.develop.com/Images/v3/tech-symbols/angularjs_logo.png';
```

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/andyw_/XxTuA/268/

If this is all you need to do - I don't think it justifies the use of a selector library or front-end framework.